# Google Api Service Account authentication access to developers data

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, picasa, service-accounts

I want to develop an application that uses the **Picasa Google API** for uploading images to my own account. I've already created the Service Account from the API Console and have created the code to upload the image (which works correctly given a valid **access_token** obtained from the OAuth2 playground).

However, when trying to obtain an access_token with the Google-api php library, this one doesn't seem to be associated to my own username (obviously, no consent screen), which throws me a **404 Not found** error message when trying to access data from my personal account.

From what I've read over at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts I could create an apps account to setup permissions for a whole domain. Is this, however, necessary given that I only want to access information from my own account? (the same I used to register the application in the API console). Couldn't this be done beforehand using API panel?

Answer (score 0):

A service account is not you and does not by default have access to any data.  Think of a service account as a dummy user.   If you take the service account email address and add it as a user on a folder in your google drive it will have access to that folder on google drive.  If you take the service account email address and give it access to one of your calendars on Google Calendar it will have access to the calendar.

If you set the album public I suspect it will then have access to the album.  I did some Googleing and I cant see how you can add another users email address to an album on [picasa](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/39551?hl=en).

I suggest you try using Oauth2.

Comment: A service account *is* a form of `OAuth2`: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount